# How to determine the svn HEAD revision commit time stamp for a particular entry with pysvn

Tags: time, commit, pysvn

I would like to determine the svn HEAD revision commit time stamp for a particular entry with pysvn. Has anyone a hint?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pysvn
import time

path = "../example.txt"
commitDate = time.strftime (
    "%Y-%m-%d",
    time.gmtime (client.info2 (path) [0] [1] ["last_changed_date"]))
```

Comment: Please, don't just post code. Try to explain why this solves the problem

Comment: I was thinking about writing something else but I didn't know what. To be honest: I don't know, why this solves the problem. I found the solution at http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html in the paragraph pysvn.Client.info2, tried it and it worked. (And, of course, I had tried to find a solution before I asked my question.)